# Constructing homeomorphisms from continuous functions and matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homeomorphism

Fix a $d\times d$ matrix $A$, let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and define the induced map $F_{f,A}:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ by
$$
x \mapsto \exp(f(x)A)x,
$$
where $\exp$ is [the matrix exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) and $f(x)A$ is defined as the point-wise scalar action of $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ on $A$.

Under what joint conditions on $f$ and $A$ does it follow that $F_{f,A}$ a homeomorphism?

For example,

- If $f(x)$ is constant then this is clearly just an element of $\operatorname{GL}_d(\mathbb{R})$
- If $f$ is radial and $A$ is in $\operatorname{SU}_d$ then this also works ([see this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00082))...

Is there a general constraint on $f$ and $A$ to make this work?

Comment: In the first bullet, should “continuous” be “constant”?

Comment: Woops! Indeed you're right

Comment: How do you define the $\exp$?

Comment: Here, I define it as the matrix exponential (and therefore the Lie exponential in this case).